# How to remove text-decoration from React <Link>?

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

This is my snippet, I am trying to remove the text-decoration from the link.

```
 <ul className="header__links">
              <Link to="/">
                <li>Home</li>
              </Link>
    </ul>
```

Here is what I have already tried:

```
.header__links{
text-decoration: none;
}
```

I tried inline CSS:

```
<Link to="/" style={{textDecoration='none'}}>
```

Then i tried targeting a tag, ul tag and li tag too but none of it seems to work. Please help me solve it.

Note: I know this question has been asked before but none of those solved my issue, which is why I am asking it.

Comment: `.header__links a {
text-decoration: none;
}` should work. Inside `.header__links` there is an `a` element. This element have some default styles that's why, `.header__links {...}` not worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I finally found the reason, it was due to some browser configurations i guess, here is the code that fixed it:

```
a:-webkit-any-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is just typo..

`style={{textDecoration='none'}}` => `style={{textDecoration: 'none'}}`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by adding inline styles to the Link tag, like so:

```
<Link to="/" style={{ textDecoration:'none' }}>
```

The reason why the op's inline code didn't work was because he used an '=' in his style rule, like so:

```
<Link to="/" style={{textDecoration='none'}}>
```

This won't work because the inline style is an object, made up of key-value pairs, thus expecting a ':' and not an '=' sign.